# onConfigurationChanged not called after coming back from an Activity with different screenOrientation Settings

Tags: android, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I have two Activities:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
<activity
    android:name=".ui.DetailActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

On some devices/emulators I have a strange error: When I am going back from the DetailActivity to the MainActivity, the device won't call `onConfigurationChanged` anymore until I click an OptionsMenu Item. After I clicked the OptionsMenu it works fine. Open the OptionsMenu programmatically however does not work.
More confusing is, that it only happens on a few devices or emulators, with different Android Versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, in the MainActivity I call `requestedOrientation` with a small delay.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
    }, 500)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you call this code?

```
    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

Comment: No, I have not overwritten these methods-

Comment: I am not talking about overriding these methods, I am saying that did you write these methods in your class??

Comment: No, it is not necessary if I do not overwrite them.

Comment: but it is necessary to define them.

Comment: What do you mean? The code you posted has no effect.